# Enzyme wrapper.state returns null

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I'm trying to check the default state of my component in my Enzyme unit tests. For this, I have the following component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Picker extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sources: true
        };
    }
}

...

export default Picker;
```

Finally, my unit test looks like this:

```
it('should contain `everything` as a default value', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Picker name='cnn' />);
  expect(wrapper.state('sources')).to.exist()
});
```

The problem I'm facing here is that, I'm unable to get the component default state. The function wrapper.state('sources') should be returning 'true' if I'm not wrong.

Is there any other step I'm missing? I'm using:

- "react": "^16.2.0"
- "chai": "^4.1.2",
- "enzyme": "^3.2.0",
- "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
- "jsdom": "^11.5.1",
- "mocha": "^4.0.1",
- "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2"

Comment: Try consoling the `wrapper.state()` and see if it prints out `{ source: true }`. If that's the case, then your `chai` assertion is wrong. I think it should be `expect(wrapper.state('sources')).to.be.true;` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @norbertpy. I managed to solve it with the answer provided by Mike Shutte below.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Then mark his answer as accepted and give him an upvote. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

I've wrestled with this a lot! Since `Picker` is a subclass of `Component`, the state you are looking for actually exists on `wrapper.instance()`, not the `wrapper`.

The "wrapper" return value of `shallow` and `mount` is just that: a wrapper. It's not the actual component you're trying to test. I think of it as a little environment that the component is surrounded by.

To make assertion on state, props, and functions on a component, I have better success reaching for:

```
const component = wrapper.instance()
```

Then on `component`, you can call `.state`, `.props`, &c.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I think you are right, @Mike Schutte... thanks for your input!

Comment: All of these may be needed(instance is no more a function but a property)   
              ......                                                                                                  
`const wrapper=TestRenderer.create(<First/>);
const component=wrapper.root;
const instance=component.instance; `                                                                         You can then use `instance.state.first` in expect statements where `first` is a state variable

Comment: So state is still null when I try to use component.instance().state. The states are set in the constructor of the class Test extends React.Component...On the latest jest/enzyme.